# Execute simultaneous commands and quit when one finishes

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I hope that question hasn't been asked too many times but I couldn't find an answer on google (I didn't know how to specify it).

Does someone know how to execute two parallel commands in bash but, when one finishes, I would like the other to finish?

For instance, I have two different python scripts :

- `while 1: pass`: loop.py
- `print(42)`: print.py

I would like to do something like `python3 loop.py ** python3 print.py`. The two scripts must run in parallel and when print finishes, loop would end automatically.

My usage of that command would be to make something like:

```
tcpdump -i any -w out.trace ** python3 network_script.py
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `&&` does not run them in parallel. It runs the first one, *then* runs the second if the first one has an exit status of 0.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
tcpdump ... & pid=$!
python3 network_script.py
kill $pid
```

Run the first script in the background, then start the second script. When the second script ends, kill the first one.

Comment: Wow, great answer :)
Shell variable $! (PID of the last executed command) was definitely what I needed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution, but you can start processes in the background with a trailing `&` and then `wait` for them to complete.

Each of those processes would have to kill all others upon completion.

It could look like this:

```
(python loop.py && killall Python) &
(python print.py && killall Python) &
wait
echo "Done with at least one!"
```

Comment: `killall Python` isn't going to be restricted to these two `python` processes.

Comment: Yes, it kills all your python processes :D But maybe you don't have any.